Fetch likes from Instagram reels
In an attempt to study Benfords law, I'm trying to get a list of the likes on recommendet Instagram Reels. So the plan is simply to open Reels, fetch the Like Count, swipe to the next Reel and repeat until I have enough data.
I'm trying to do this in Python with the Selenium Webdriver:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pyautogui
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")  # open instagram
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Allow all cookies"]').click()  # allow cookies
time.sleep(3)
user_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username")  # enter username
user_field.send_keys("my_username")
user_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
password_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password")  # enter password
password_field.send_keys("my_password")
password_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(5)
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/reels')  # go to reels
for i in range(1, 5):  # swipe 5 reels then just wait
    time.sleep(5)
    # get how many likes the reel has (this doesn't seem to update)
    div_element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.html-div.xe8uvvx.xdj266r.x11i5rnm.x1mh8g0r.xexx8yu.x4uap5.x18d9i69.xkhd6sd.x6s0dn4.x1ypdohk.x78zum5.xdt5ytf.xieb3on')
    # get likes by xpath (doesn't work crashes program)
    # div_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mount_0_0_vZ"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/section/main/div[2]/div[9]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/span/span')
    # get all the buttons (works but there is alot of other unnecessay data)
    # div_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@role="button"]')
    like_text = div_element.text
    print(like_text)  # print out the likes
    time.sleep(3)
    pyautogui.press('down')  # swipe to next reel

time.sleep(5000)


In the code I'm trying to access the highlighted span element in the picture:

This span block seems to be identical for all other reels with the exception of the like count.
But if I run the code it fails to update the like count, so it outputs:
165K
165K
165K
165K

I've tried to acess this element by all sorts of methods (XPATH, CSS_SELECTOR, NAME, ID,...) some of them crash others return nothing. Any ideas what to do?

Could it be that the old reel isn't removed from the DOM when you scroll, and find_element is returning the first match, which never changes? If you try find_elements instead, do you get multiple matches with different values?

@Daniel Yes that was it. In this case find_elements also returned the number of comments, but that's okay; one more dataset. If you write a answer I can give you the bounty.

As mentioned in the comments, it could be that the old reel isn't removed from the DOM when you scroll. Because find_element returns only the first match, that value would never change if earlier reels remain in the DOM. Instead, try find_elements and grab the desired value.

The problem you're facing is likely due to how Instagram dynamically loads content. The initial HTML you see might not contain the updated like count for subsequent reels.
Use Explicit Waits
Instead of relying on fixed time.sleep delays, use Selenium's WebDriverWait with an expected condition to wait for the like count element to be updated.
You can use ExpectedConditions.presence_of_element_located or ExpectedConditions.text_to_be_present_in_element depending on your needs
Demo Psudo Code:
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# ... Your Existing Code  ...
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)  # Set a wait time of 10 seconds
like_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.html-div.xe8uvvx...)))
like_text = like_element.text
print(like_text)


Thank you for your answer, but it didn't really work, the code behaves exactly the same: It prints the likes of the first reel over and over again. Furthermore, if I don't put a time.sleep into the loop the bot swipes down without pausing.
